# accentuated characters plotly

Tags: html, plotly, offline

I'm having a problem with the div generated with this code :

```
plot(fig, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')
```

All the accentuated letter are in html entities, how can I have a div with this entities decoded?

Thks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add more code? Ideally to have a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example": https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve